# Google API to get data from BigQuery Table

Tags: google-bigquery, google-apis-explorer

I am trying to get data from BigQuery Table with Python. I am aware that **BigQuery Connector** is available and I can export table using that. However I don't want to involve the **GCS (Google Cloud Storage)**, and that where the things get tricky.

I could see that there are few API call through which I can get whole table data. 
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tabledata/list

And another way is I can query the BigQuery Table. 
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query

However I am not able to understand how exactly I need to query those API using **Python** or **JAVA**?

How to create a client ? or how to authenticate?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python

Comment: @ElliottBrossard I know how to create client for bigquery, however it doesn't have method to execute this REST calls

Comment: https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bigquery/usage.html#table-operations. It even has an example titled "Browse selected rows in a table"

Comment: what do you mean _"However I don't want to involve the GCP"_? BigQuery is part of GCP, so you're already using the platform. The way you are proposing won't scale. The best option is to export to GCS, download and then read into whatever application you're building.

Comment: @GrahamPolley I meant don't want to store anything temporary in **GCS**

Comment: @ElliottBrossard could you sum up your comments as an answer? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by @GrahamPolley you can follow [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python) where is explained how to:

Authenticate:

> To run the client library, you must first set up authentication by
>   creating a service account and setting an environment variable.

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/path/to/auth/[FILE_NAME].json"
```

Create a client:

```
BigQueryClient client = BigQueryClient.Create(projectId);
```

And for browsing data in selected table you can use an example from [official library documentation](https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bigquery/usage.html#table-operations):

```
# from google.cloud import bigquery
# client = bigquery.Client()

dataset_ref = client.dataset('samples', project='bigquery-public-data')
table_ref = dataset_ref.table('shakespeare')
table = client.get_table(table_ref)  # API call

# Load all rows from a table
rows = client.list_rows(table)
assert len(list(rows)) == table.num_rows

# Load the first 10 rows
rows = client.list_rows(table, max_results=10)
assert len(list(rows)) == 10

# Specify selected fields to limit the results to certain columns
fields = table.schema[:2]  # first two columns
rows = client.list_rows(table, selected_fields=fields, max_results=10)
assert len(rows.schema) == 2
assert len(list(rows)) == 10

# Use the start index to load an arbitrary portion of the table
rows = client.list_rows(table, start_index=10, max_results=10)

# Print row data in tabular format
format_string = '{!s:<16} ' * len(rows.schema)
field_names = [field.name for field in rows.schema]
print(format_string.format(*field_names))  # prints column headers
for row in rows:
    print(format_string.format(*row))      # prints row data
```